# MDC: Material3 MaterialCalendar Background Color

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, mdc-components, material3

How to change Material Calendar background? I am setting a day and night theme and it is working except for the night mode where the set color background is not applied correctly.

This is the expected background color in night

[image]

This is the actual background color in night

[image]

Despite having the same value of `colorSurface` with regular `MaterialAlertDialog`,  `MaterialCalendar` cannot follow this specific color.

```
<!-- DatePicker theme on both light and night mode -->
    <style name="AppCalendar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialCalendar" tools:keep="@style/AppCalendar">
        <!-- Background color -->
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorWhite_Primary</item>
        <!-- Indicator or focused field color -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary_Accent</item>
        <!-- Day color (active) -->
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorWhite_PrimaryDark</item>
        <!-- Day color (inactive) -->
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorPrimaryDark_White</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/colorPrimary_Accent</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceCornerExtraLarge">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.LargeComponent</item>
    </style>

    <!-- AlertDialog theme on both light and night mode -->
    <style name="AppDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialAlertDialog" tools:keep="@style/AppDialog">
        <!-- Background color -->
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorWhite_Primary</item>
        <!-- Message color -->
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark_White</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App</item>
    </style>
```

Usage

```
 <!-- Base application theme -->
 <style name="Theme.Sample" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">

        <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/AppCalendar</item>

        <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/AppDialog</item>

 </style>
```

To confirm if we are pointing to a correct attribute, changing `colorSurface` value to `@android:color/holo_orange_dark` will result to this.

[image]

What is the issue here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution

```
<item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
```

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1133

Answer (score 1):

You can use it

```
<item name="colorSurfaceContainerHigh">YourColor</item>
```

When examined as a source, the source code of this [color](https://www.figma.com/file/iHtbr5lFK6DowjWkJCZ3Hw/Material-3-Design-Kit-(Community)?type=design&node-id=49823-12142&mode=design&t=0Hvj3VjNM852IYqW-0)

All other [sources](https://www.figma.com/file/iHtbr5lFK6DowjWkJCZ3Hw/Material-3-Design-Kit-(Community)?type=design&node-id=49823-12142&mode=design&t=0Hvj3VjNM852IYqW-0)

Comment: I actually already tried this after reading Material 3 documentation but it didn't work.

 https://m3.material.io/components/date-pickers/specs#e85d93da-1a4f-4750-b1bd-03e6c62d2bca

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialCalendar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_color</item>
    <item name="elevationOverlayColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="elevationOverlayAccentColor">@color/white</item>

</style>
```